# "AndroidManifest file does not exist" error in azure pipeline

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use azure devops to setup automatic build for my xamarin android application.
I used the default Xamarin.Android build template

```
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  demands:
  - MSBuild
  - Xamarin.Android
  - JDK

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

This gives me an error on build

```
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2752297Z Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTry\XamarinFormsTry.Android\obj\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj.nuget.g.props.
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2752837Z Generating MSBuild file d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTry\XamarinFormsTry.Android\obj\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2753312Z Writing assets file to disk. Path: d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTryStandard\obj\project.assets.json
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2753766Z Writing assets file to disk. Path: d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTry\XamarinFormsTry.Android\obj\project.assets.json
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2754231Z Writing cache file to disk. Path: d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTryStandard\obj\project.nuget.cache
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2754658Z Restore completed in 47.34 sec for d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTryStandard\XamarinFormsTry.csproj.
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2755110Z Writing cache file to disk. Path: d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTry\XamarinFormsTry.Android\obj\project.nuget.cache
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2755614Z Restore completed in 47.57 sec for d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTry\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj.
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2755964Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2756107Z NuGet Config files used:
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2756322Z     d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_19.config
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2756470Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2756630Z Feeds used:
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2756825Z     https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2756980Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2757113Z Installed:
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2757302Z     1 package(s) to packages.config projects
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2757610Z     13 package(s) to d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTryStandard\XamarinFormsTry.csproj
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2758035Z     169 package(s) to d:\a\1\s\XamarinFormsTry\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2773237Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGetCommand
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2807591Z ##[section]Starting: XamarinAndroid
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2947509Z ==============================================================================
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2947864Z Task         : Xamarin.Android
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2948151Z Description  : Build an Android app with Xamarin
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2948500Z Version      : 1.166.0
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2948736Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2949074Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xamarin-android
2020-03-26T09:12:32.2949464Z ==============================================================================
2020-03-26T09:12:34.4220559Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\XamarinAndroid_27edd013-36fd-43aa-96a3-7d73e1e35285\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
2020-03-26T09:12:34.4661105Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\XamarinAndroid_27edd013-36fd-43aa-96a3-7d73e1e35285\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json
2020-03-26T09:12:34.5348014Z ##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\XamarinAndroid_27edd013-36fd-43aa-96a3-7d73e1e35285\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
2020-03-26T09:12:34.7801263Z ##[warning]Unable to find MSBuild version '15.0' for architecture 'x86'. Falling back to version '16.0'.
2020-03-26T09:12:34.8662182Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\XamarinAndroid_27edd013-36fd-43aa-96a3-7d73e1e35285\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=b1e39c46-8802-47e2-b5ab-4bec5fda9203|SolutionDir=d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\XamarinAndroid_27edd013-36fd-43aa-96a3-7d73e1e35285\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:configuration="Release" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_efe7950b-580b-467b-8a98-19b6043eee2e_build_1_0" /t:PackageForAndroid /p:OutputPath="d:\a\1\b/Release"
2020-03-26T09:12:34.9957257Z Build started 3/26/2020 9:12:34 AM.
2020-03-26T09:12:35.2054286Z Project "d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj" on node 1 (PackageForAndroid target(s)).
2020-03-26T09:12:35.2062946Z _CleanIntermediateIfNuGetsChange:
2020-03-26T09:12:35.2066241Z   Creating directory "obj\Release\90\stamp\".
2020-03-26T09:12:35.2070062Z   Creating "obj\Release\90\stamp\_CleanIntermediateIfNuGetsChange.stamp" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
2020-03-26T09:12:35.8847743Z _ResolveSdks:
2020-03-26T09:12:35.8850229Z   Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
2020-03-26T09:12:36.3595388Z   Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8133556Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(752,2): Error : AndroidManifest file does not exist
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8136850Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(752,2): error : AndroidManifest file does not exist [d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj]
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8167951Z Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj" (PackageForAndroid target(s)) -- FAILED.
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8205677Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8208249Z Build FAILED.
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8258005Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8270145Z "d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj" (PackageForAndroid target) (1) ->
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8274063Z (_ValidateAndroidPackageProperties target) -> 
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8277799Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(752,2): error : AndroidManifest file does not exist [d:\a\1\s\MigrationBackup\b36c964d\XamarinFormsTry.Android\XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj]
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8279308Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8281145Z     0 Warning(s)
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8284488Z     1 Error(s)
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8286684Z 
2020-03-26T09:12:36.8290589Z Time Elapsed 00:00:01.83
2020-03-26T09:12:36.9547149Z ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
2020-03-26T09:12:37.1765717Z ##[section]Finishing: XamarinAndroid
2020-03-26T09:12:44.6607030Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout XamarinFormsTry@master to s
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(752,2): Error : AndroidManifest file does not exist 
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

I know that my project builds just fine as I can build it on my mac and pc using Visual studio for mac and Visual Studio 2019
and
I am also using https://appcenter.ms (Microsoft AppCenter) for analytics and that too provides a build on commit option. Even that builds just fine using a similar build agent process.

I have tried making a copy of AndroidManifest.xml and placing it in the root but that does not work either.

here is the configuration block from the .proj file for the Xamarin.Android project

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{C6CD5F2A-47C8-4A53-9729-91C88CEEB870}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>XamarinFormsTry.Droid</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>XamarinFormsTry.Android</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AndroidApplication>true</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v10.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidStoreUncompressedFileExtensions />
    <MandroidI18n />
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize />
    <JavaOptions />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <AndroidKeyStore>false</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>*******</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass />
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>true</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[image: The AndroidManifest.xml file at relative path in repo]

It probably is something silly on my end, but I am unable to find help on google or figure it out myself.

Comment: I have create a sample with `Xamarin.Android`, and build it with your yaml file. It works fine (Just 10 warnings, no error. ). So, your yaml file should be correct, you need make sure you could build your project on `windows-latest` successfully. Or you can try to build it with agent `macos-latest`, check if it works fine.

Comment: I did that too. still didn't work. My project is a xamarin forms project and that is the one specified to be built. I am going to see if changing the relative path to the full path of the droid csproj file works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone who has a xamarin.forms .net standard way kind of project and is running into a similar error here is what fixed it for me.

the original pipline

```
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  demands:
  - MSBuild
  - Xamarin.Android
  - JDK

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

the fixed pipeline (yes the error was in the pipeline)

```
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  demands:
  - MSBuild
  - Xamarin.Android
  - JDK

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: 'XamarinFormsTry/XamarinFormsTry.Android/XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

So its not that it didn't find the AndroidManifest file
it didnt find the right proj file.
changing the `projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'` to `projectFile: 'XamarinFormsTry/XamarinFormsTry.Android/XamarinFormsTry.Android.csproj'`
 works. The right proj file is found and the proj builds successfully.
the error and the logs are a bit misleading in this case I guess

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error for .NET MAUI and I figured out that the project ID was wrong in .csproj